# SQL query on multiple column order by

Tags: sql, select, join, if-statement, sql-order-by

Here in 3 table X , Y , Z . If I join them it results like.

```
Subject   Semester   Attendee
---------------------------------
ITB001    1          John
ITB001    1          Bob
ITB001    1          Mickey
ITB001    2          Jenny
ITB001    2          James
MKB114    1          John
MKB114    1          Erica
```

But I want to show them like following :

```
Subject   Semester   Attendee
---------------------------------
ITB001    1          John
                     Bob
                     Mickey
          2          Jenny
                     James
MKB114    1          John
                     Erica
```

.

```
select x.name, y.name, z.name from x,y,z where y.x_id=x.id and z.y_id=y.id
```

But how to change the sql query?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, ...)?

Comment: I am using MySQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

For `MySQL`

```
SELECT IF(@Subject = @Subject:=X.id, '', X.name) AS `Subject`, 
       IF(@Semester = @Semester:=Y.id, '', Y.name) AS `Semester`, 
       Z.name 
FROM X
INNER JOIN Y ON Y.x_id=X.id 
INNER JOIN Z ON Z.y_id=Y.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Subject:=0, @Semester:=0) A
ORDER BY X.id, Y.id, Z.id
```

Comment: @Mashfuk You're most welcome. If You find your solution then accept the answer which will fulfill your requirement by clicking on true mark left side of the answer

Answer (score 3):

It's a matter of **presentation** of data not data retrieval. Therefore you **don't do that on the database side** but rather in your client code (whatever it happens to be C#/ASP.NET, php, java...).